# Firebase share authenticated user between 2 angular apps (Single Sign On)

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have two angular apps. Both use the same firebase project...

I would like to have a single sign on (either app A or app B) and have the user be logged in both app A and app B.

I am new to firebase auth and i don't have a clear idea on how to do this.

Comment: If you're not using the same Firebase app in the background, I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two web Angular Apps and the idea is to use a single sign on either app A or app B and have the user be logged in both app A and app B.
A solution to this is to use a method to sign in with a custom token by sharing the JWT token between the apps:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
```

Firebase gives you complete control over authentication by allowing you to authenticate users or devices using secure JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). You generate these tokens on your server, pass them back to a client device, and then use them to authenticate via the signInWithCustomToken() method. That is, signInWithCustomToken is meant to be used with your own tokens minted on your own server. Explore more on this from the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

Also, have a look at the [GitHub Link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2291).

Comment: I have posted an answer. Can you check if that helps?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can i share that TOKEN between the two angular apps, i don't have a server app and i am using firebase cloud functions.

Comment: You may have a look at this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

Comment: Wondering if you had to deploy multiple targets on Firebase Hosting in order to have the two angular apps accessing the same authentication service (single sign-on like)